# Are premium store upgrades permanent?

Tags: bloons-td-5

Are the 3 upgrades; Double cash mode, health bananas and Bigger beacons, in the premium store permanent upgrades or for a limited number of games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got enough money together to test this.

The premium store upgrades are toggable bonuses:
[image: Premium Store screenshot on Android]

Nothing on them indicates that they should run out.